# In the Bixby Simulator is it possible to toggle between dev and production config?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I would like to be able to toggle between "pointing at" dev & production config/secrets in the Bixby IDE Simulator. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in IDE the compile capsule always point to DEV.

However, you can easily switch between DEV and PRD by using revision override feature in IDE. Private revision points to DEV and public revision points to PRD.

If you believe this feature is critical, you can raise a [Feature Request](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/360000183273-Feature-Requests) in our community. This forum is open to other Bixby developers who can upvote it, leading to more visibility within the community and with the Product Management team.

Comment: I don't know about "critical", but important.  the ability to point to public (previous) revisions does not help me with making sure that code I am testing works with real data.

Comment: You can always submit new public submission for testing purpose.